# Angular directive link function never runs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I followed the tutorial of ng-bbok, and at the directive definition an empty `compile` function is inserted and then the `link` function. With this the code in the `link`  function never got executed. Finally i figured out that is because the empty `compile` function, when i deleted it magically the `link` got executed. Why is it happening like this? Im using Angular 1.3

`{
  compile: function() {},
  link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
    var size = attributes.gravatarSize || 80;
    var hash = md5.digest_s($scope.email.from[0]);
    $scope.gravatarImage = url + hash + '?size=' + size;
  }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define both `compile` property and `link`. If you want to use the `compile` function you can either return the link function:

```
compile: function() {
    return function($scope, element, attributes) {
        var size = attributes.gravatarSize || 80;
        var hash = md5.digest_s($scope.email.from[0]);
        $scope.gravatarImage = url + hash + '?size=' + size;
    }
}
```

Or define both `pre` and `post` (link) functions:

```
compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
  return {
    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
  }
}
```

Check the [documentation](http://documentation)

Answer (score 0):

It's happening by design. To quote the [$compile docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> ### link
>
> This property is used only if the compile property is not defined.